# weird c:/boot folder after installing ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

so i installed ubuntu yesterday and everything was working great i can boot into both os but i've noticed something strange which is boot folder and bootmgr in c partition that wasn't there before plus duplicate windows entries in grub menu the first one says: windows7 dev/sda1 and the second one says: windows7 dev/sda4 ,i can boot into both of them and then i realised the windows7 dev/sda1 is system reserved partition which is the default windows7 boot , and yesterday i booted into windows dev/sda4 instead

Comment: Next time when you post a question here, it'd be nice if you actually asked a question instead of stating that you found something. Boot and bootmgr folders are normally hidden by Windows so you don't mess with them. They existed before, you can just see them now. I'm not as sure about the sda1 and sda2 Windows 7 options but I assume one is for UEFI boot and the other isn't... either that or some odd side effect of dual booting (which I never, ever recommend to do). Someone else may have more insight.

Comment: after some researches i found out that the boot folder and bootmgr are showing is because after booting into windows dev/sda4 which marks the partition C: as active instead of system reserved , and this causes windows to put the boot folder and bootmgr in C: partition instead of system reserved, so all i need is to remove the windows dev/sda4 boot entry from grub menu.